# How to move files written with Pandas on Spark cluster to HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I'm running a Spark Job using Cluster Mode and writing few files using Pandas and I think it's writing in temp directory, now I want to move these files or write these files in HDFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options:

- convert Pandas Dataframe into PySpark DataFrame and simply save it into HDFS

```py
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
spark_df.write.parquet("hdfs:///path/on/hdfs/file.parquet")
```

- save file locally using Pandas and use `subprocess` to copy file to HDFS

```py
import subprocess

command = "hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -f local/file.parquet /path/on/hdfs".split()
result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```

- save file locally and use 3rd party library - [hdfs3](https://pypi.org/project/hdfs3/) - to copy file to HDFS

```py
from hdfs3 import HDFileSystem

hdfs = HDFileSystem()
hdfs.cp("local/file.parquet", "/path/on/hdfs")
```